# Wireless charging shielding requirements

Tags: rf, battery-charging, wireless-charging, emf

I have a project where I want to throw a charging coil into the wonderful mix of tiny parts but the problem is, I also need an accelerometer/magnetometer roughly right beside said coil. I believe I need some sort of shield around either the circuit or the coil probably an EMF shield but I can't really find much info on this since looking at phones, they seem to use some weird graphite copper plate thing. I don't think leaving it unsheilded would be very nice and all the other things in proximity of that thing would be unhappy. I plan on using something like 500 mA of charging power but I can scale down or up if there is headroom.

*What is necessary for my circuit to not think north is literally every way possible?*

I would prefer to solder something to the PCB instead of shielding the coil since it's probably going to need to be connected to ground.

(P.S. I think what im looking for is a ferrite EMI plate?)

Comment: What is the frequency of the coil charging current?

Comment: @FiddyOhm reading a bit into what coil to use, since I want a low power coil to QI standards at least, i'm probably going to use 110KHz to 205KHz, I dont know if I can get away with having a ground layer in the PCB to shield from both sides

Comment: It seems like there are more nuances to this question which explains why I couldn't easily find an answer, I'll do some more research into this lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not test your magnetometer close to a different working wireless charger first?

There are two possible problems:

1. the charging fields directly affecting the magnetometer. This is possible, but it feels not very likely as the frequency is so high. Look at the datasheet. Test a part on a working wireless charger or in a TEM cell. To be sure you could put a metal screen over the part, this will reduce the fields by thousands of times. A screen containing iron or nickel will degrade the compass, so use only copper.
   Finally, check the wireless charger circuit that there is definitely no DC on the coil. Either C in series or L in parallel. DC
2. the fields could couple into the i2c tracks on the board and affect the communication. This is not going to be a problem if you have a continuous ground plane. At 13 MHz the tracks are not good antennas. If the board passes EMC with clock and data at several MHz, it won't pick up the fields either.

Also take apart some phones and chargers. In my experience phones have their coil not far above a ground plane. They also keep the magnetometer in one corner away from DC but also away from the charger. Chargers have a ferrite plate, but not as a shield, just to concentrate the fields on one side, they don't have a PCB behind the coil.

Comment: I was asking in advance since I dont have the parts yet. I like to design the board first then iterate until it works if it doesnt work (saves money)